# Create a non-interactive PowerShell script that accepts the following parameters on the command line:

Tags: powershell, scripting

please to help me.
How to create a PowerShell script for this:
Create a non-interactive PowerShell script that accepts the following parameters on the command line:

```
a. ProjectStart
b. ProjectEnd
c. PhaseStart
d. PhaseEnd
So, if the user supplied 1, 3, 1, and 2 as corresponding parameter values, then the following folder
structure shall be created:
C:\Projects\Project1\Phase1
C:\Projects\Project1\Phase2
C:\Projects\Project2\Phase1
C:\Projects\Project2\Phase2
C:\Projects\Project3\Phase1
C:\Projects\Project3\Phase2
```

Comment: Server Fault is a question and answer site for managing information technology systems in a business environment. You could ask your question in superuser.com, but also include what you have done to answer it.

Comment: How far are you? Do you already have a first draft of the script?